# Input camera not opening on webview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webview

```
<label for="input-3">
    <img class="img-upload img-responsive" src="ico.png" /><input id="input-3" type="file" class="" name="photos" accept="image/*" style="display:none;">
</label>
```

I tried this code on mobile browser android and iOS, and works perfect but on the webview nothing happens..the input it's not lunching. What to do?

Comment: What do you mean on the web view?

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel an app on android..and my friend introduce an webview..

Comment: It seems like there is well known bug (? maybe a security feature) with webviews where the app that generated the webview has to manually handle and pass-through the camera event for that to appear. TL;DR: its a problem with the Android app, not your webpage

Comment: @Upoings1975 try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41570241/3518278