# Opening camera from android webView

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'm trying to open the android native camera from an html page loaded in a android webView
by using HTML input type file tag.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

I have no idea why but the camera is not opening and I don't know what to do.

I've tried the same page on a iPhone webView and it's working.

What can I do?

Comment: correct me if im wrong but your trying to open the camera  from a html page correct?

Answer (score 5):

If i understand your question correctly

You want to open the android device camera on click of a button in the webpage(html)?

On the basis of that assumption,
You need to do the following

Use a **JavascriptInterface**

```
public class WebVCamBridgeInterface {
        /**
         * Javacript function to start native camera
         */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void takePicture() {
            captureImage();
        }

        /**
         * Javascript function to start the GalleryActivity for user to choose the  image to be uploaded
         */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showPictures() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LandingActivity.this, GalleryActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQ_GALLERY);
        }

    }
```

add JSinterface to your webview

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebVCamBridgeInterface (), "AndroidDevice");
```

Have the following JS in your html/web page

```
<script>
  function takePicture() {
    if(typeof AndroidDevice !== "undefined"){
      AndroidDevice.takePicture();
    }
  }

  function showPictures() {
    if(typeof AndroidDevice !== "undefined"){
      AndroidDevice.showPictures();
    }
  }

  function imageData(data){
    document.getElementById('displayImage').setAttribute( 'src', 'data:image/png;base64,'+data );
    if(typeof AndroidDevice !== "undefined"){
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Im providing the link to a sample project with video of a demo ,have a look.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwRMp8dK9LMLeEo5cTlXVE9ZUW8?resourcekey=0-6dEjytPymBZvebmmyy9ymQ&usp=sharing**

You can also refer these tutorials

- [Upload Image/File from Gallery or Camera in WebView in Android](https://infeeds.com/d/CODEmgks/20475/upload-image-file-gallery-or-camera-webv)
- [Android Smart WebView with advanced features](https://infeeds.com/d/CODEmgks/25019/android-smart-webview-open-source-upload)
- [Open File Chooser with camera option in webview](http://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128)

cheers!.