# How to use camera as a source from a file input inside Facebook Android Webview

Tags: android, facebook, webview

We have a HTML5 page with a file input:

```
<input accept="image/*" type="file">
```

Now in Chrome, Safari, Firefox (both Android or iOS) and inside the webview of Facebook iOS this will allow selecting an image from the camera roll or the camera.

Yet when using this on an Android inside the Facebook Webview it will only give options like Images / Recent / Google Drive / Photos but no camera.

Is this a bug or a Facebook conscious option? Is there any way of using the phone camera as a source for the image inside the webview of Facebook Android?

Comment: How did you solve this ?
Same problem here and it is a big problem in our case.
For some reason, it works in iOS but not android...

Comment: @Taiko Hi there. I went over the code and I posted what I believe to be the final solution here. Basically I used <video> to capture from the camera. I really didn't test it but if I remember correctly it did solve my problem at the time

Answer (score 2):

In the end my solution for this issue was to create a video element with a localstream:

```
var videoCamera = document.createElement('video');
videoCamera.setAttribute("id", "video");
videoCamera.setAttribute("height", 320);
videoCamera.setAttribute("width", 480);
videoCamera.setAttribute("video", true);
videoCamera.autoPlay = true;
$('#video-container').prepend(videoCamera);


if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
     video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
     video.play();
     localStream = stream;
  });
}
```

Then I'll have a button that will basically get the current frame and put it on a canvas:

```
 var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
 canv.width = $('#video').width();
 canv.height = $('#video').height();

 var ctx=canv.getContext("2d");

 ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0,$('#video').width(), $('#video').height());
 ctx.restore();
 localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
```

Once you can get the snapshot on a canvas then you can just export it to Base64:

```
canv.toDataURL();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but Try to add `capture="camera"`

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Comment: Already tried <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">

<input type="file" accept="image/*;" capture="camera">

<input type="file" accept="image/*;" capture>

<input type="file" capture>

<input type="file">

<input type="file" multiple="multiple" />

<input type="file" accept="image/*">

Comment: okay, have you tried this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41570241/5602752

Comment: It's not my webview... We just have a HTML5 page that, when opened in Facebook browser (for example when you click the link from the feed) the file input behaviour is different from everything else